# Running IPython Notebook on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to run the IPython notebook server on Google App Engine (GAE)?

I understand that GAE restricts some libraries from running on its servers. I have also read a couple of SO threads where users have tried to run ipdb (debugger) on GAE. I also understand that IPython will not run on GAE out of the box. I am willing to spend some time in understanding IPython internals and porting it to run on GAE, but I don't understand its various dependencies and if any of those dependencies are blocked on GAE.

If you have already tried this, could you share your experience. If not, do you know if this is even feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the IPython notebook server to run on App Engine alone is probably infeasible.  Each notebook would need its own iPython kernel, which must either run continuously or have a way to persist its state between requests.  In theory, you might be able to use a combination of server classes where clients could run on scalable frontends and kernels could run on persistent backends.  But you'd have to replace all of the ZeroMQ+Tornado guts to do this.  (I'm not intimately familiar with iPython server guts, but this is the impression I got from talking with iPython devs at conferences, plus a little reading.)

Compute Engine is more plausible, in the obvious way: just run the server like you would on any Linux box.  Porting just the web client to App Engine and using a pool of kernels running on GCE might be a path to success depending on what you're trying to accomplish, but it'd still be a major project to offer it as a managed, scalable service.

Here's a thread on the subject from two years ago: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-notebook/re2bUt4vCxA

And here's an (old?) project involving both GAE and AWS, though from this page alone it sounds like it uses GAE only for the maintenance interface and not for the notebook client: https://notebookcloud.appspot.com/docs

Comment: Thanks Dan. I need to host IPython notebook for experimentation. I was trying to understand if it would be possible to do so on the App Engine with some effort. From your response, it looks like it will be a major project. I plan to host IPython on a local server now. I might delve into IPython internals later for academic interest.

Comment: If it's just for your own use and doesn't need to scale to thousands of users, you might try just running it on a Compute Engine instance.  Be sure to secure it with a password. http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/public_server.html

Comment: It's mainly for my own use and a few others. The link you posted was very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

Old question, and app engine answer (don't) still stands.  But in case anyone comes back to this, the easiest way to run iPython (either locally or via GCE) these days is via docker.  These days, launching my iPython is as easy as navigating to the right directory and typing "docker-compose up".  I use python 3.x, and my docker-compose yml is simple:

```
nb:
  image: andaag/sklearn_notebook3
  ports: 
    - "8888:8888"
  volumes: 
    - "/:/ml"
```

That's it!  pull andaag's image and you're good to go. Of course, you can find or bake your own image.

Have fun!